# Print a non-clashing binary search tree

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, binary-tree

### Brief

- Print an ASCII representation of a binary search tree.
- You should write your own minimum implementation logic of a BST (node, left, right, insert)

```
(50,30,70,20,80,40,75,90) gives:

__50__70__80__90
   |       |
   |       |__75
   |
   |__30__40
       |
       |__20
```

### Detailed requirements

- Items are inserted into the tree in the order in which they are in the list
- All node values are right aligned in columns.
- Right nodes are joined using `__`
- Right nodes are represented along the horizontal and appear directly to the right of the parent node
- Right nodes are separated by a minimum of 2 underscores (__)
- Left nodes are joined using `|` and `|__` on the next line
- Left nodes are represented along the vertical and appear under and to the right of the parent (ie, next column).
- Left nodes are separated by a a minimum of a blank line (discounting pipes (|) linking child to parent)
- The vertical pipes joining 2 left nodes should be in the column directly under the last character of the parent node (see samples)
- Column width is determined using something like `max(col_values[]).toString().length() + 2`
- Branching left always adds a new row to the tree diagram
- 2 separate (left) branches never appear on the same line (right__right__right is OK)
- The root node may optionally be prefixed with `__` (Removing it just about doubled my test code!)
- Input is a set of positive and/or negative integers
- You do not need to deal with duplicate values (drop/ignore them)
- I'm not placing many restrictions on trailing whitespaces:

  - You may have trailing whitespaces after the last node on a line
  - You may have trailing whitespace after a `|` on the empty lines
  - No whitespace between nodes when when branching right
- Standard loopholes and T&Cs apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes wins!

I'm aware that this is a potential duplicate, but I think I've been specific enough in my requirements that it should pose new challenges.

### Sample Input/Output

- Input

  ```
  (50,40,30,20,10)
  ```
- Output

  ```
  __50
     |
     |__40
         |
         |__30
             |
             |__20
                 |
                 |__10
  ```
- Input

  ```
  (10,20,30,40,50)
  ```
- Output

  ```
  __10__20__30__40__50
  ```
- Input

  ```
  (50,700,30,800,60,4,5,10,20,2,500,850,900,950,870,35,1,-10)
  ```
- Output

  ```
  __50__700__800__850__900__950
     |    |              |
     |    |              |__870
     |    |
     |    |___60__500
     |
     |___30___35
          |
          |____4____5___10___20
               |
               |____2
                    |
                    |____1
                         |
                         |__-10
  ```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/849/8478)

Comment: @MartinBüttner yup, that's the one I was trying to be different enough from!

Comment: Is this challenge too simple? Boring? Trivial? Uninteresting? Would appreciate some feedback so I can pose better challenges.

Comment: I don't think it's any of those. If anything the challenge is fairly hard. That's not a bad thing though, but it can mean that it receives less attention.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't think it was too hard - perhaps it's the nature of the problem. Some challenges seem (to me, at least) to be far more complicated and they receive a few answers.  No problem though. I enjoyed writing it and having to solve it too. Good exercise for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Java <strike>1286</strike> <strike>1106</strike> 1100 bytes

Here's an easy entry to beat ;-)

Pretty messy. I traverse the tree, populating a 2d array with the node values (and left branch pipes), and a size array with the maximum column widths. Then print the node array using size array to determine correct horizontal spacing.  I look forward to seeing a better way of doing this.

```
class N{N l,r;int v,i,h,g,b,e,c,j;String[][]a=new String[10][10];int[]w=new int[10];String o="",p="";N(int x){v=x;}void i(int n){if(n>v)if(r==null)r=new N(n);else r.i(n);else if(n<v)if(l==null)l=new N(n);else l.i(n);}void p(N node){a[b][h]=""+node.v;if(w[h]<a[b][h].length())w[h]=a[b][h].length();if(node.r!=null){h++;p(node.r);h--;}if(node.l!=null){b++;while(g<b)a[++g][h]="|";h++;p(node.l);if(a[--g][--h].equals("|"))g--;}}void d(){for(e=-1;++e<a.length;){o="";for(j=-1;++j<a[0].length;){p=a[e][j];if(p!=null)if(p.equals("|")){for(i=0;i++<w[j]-p.length()+2;)o+=" "; o+=p;}else for(i=0;i++<w[j]+2;)o+=" ";else for(i=0;i++<=w[j]+1;)o+=" ";}if(!o.trim().equals(""))System.out.println(o);o="";for(c=-1;++c<a[0].length;){p=a[e][c];if(p!=null)if(p.equals("|")){for(i=0;i++<w[c]-p.length()+2;)o+=" ";o+=p;}else{for(i=0;i++<w[c]-p.length()+2;)o+="_"; o+=p; }else for(i=0;i++<=w[c]+1;)o+=" ";}if(!o.trim().equals(""))System.out.println(o);}}public static void main(String[]a){String[]q=a[0].split(",");N t=new N(Integer.parseInt(q[0]));for(int i=0;i++<q.length-1;)t.i(Integer.parseInt(q[i]));t.p(t);t.d();}}
```

```
__50__700__800__850__900__950        
   |    |              |             
   |    |              |__870        
   |    |                            
   |    |___60__500                  
   |                                 
   |___30___35                       
        |                            
        |____4____5___10___20        
             |                       
             |____2                  
                  |                  
                  |____1             
                       |             
                       |__-10
```

**Ungolfed**

```
class N {
    N leftNode, rightNode;
    int index, loop, curRight, curDown, maxDown, row,col;
    String[][] nodes = new String[10][10]; 
    int[] colWidths = new int[10];
    String line = "", node="";
```

`N(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

void i(int newValue) {
    if (newValue > index) {
        if (rightNode == null) {
            rightNode = new N(newValue);
        }
        else {
            rightNode.i(newValue);
        }
    }
    else if (newValue < index) {
        if (leftNode == null) {
            leftNode = new N(newValue);
        }
        else {
            leftNode.i(newValue);
        }
    }
}


void p(N node) {
    // Push current node
    nodes[maxDown][curRight] = ""+node.index;
    // Keep track of max column widths
    if (colWidths[curRight] < nodes[maxDown][curRight].length()) {
        colWidths[curRight] = nodes[maxDown][curRight].length();
    }
    // Branch right
    if (node.rightNode != null) {
        curRight++;
        p(node.rightNode);
        curRight--;
    }
    // Branch left
    if (node.leftNode != null) {
        maxDown++;
        while (curDown<maxDown){
            nodes[++curDown][curRight] = "|";
        }
        curRight++;
        p(node.leftNode);
        if (nodes[--curDown][--curRight].equals("|")) { //following the ladder back up
            curDown--;
        }
    }
}

void d() {
    for ( row = -1; ++row < nodes.length;) {
        // Sloppy. Inject extra rows to extend pipes (double spacing)
        line = "";
        for (int col = -1; ++col < nodes[0].length;) {
            node = nodes[row][col];
            if (node!=null){
                if (node.equals("|")) {
                    for (loop=0; loop++< colWidths[col] - node.length() + 2; ){
                        line+=" ";
                    }
                    line+=node;
                }
                else {
                    for (loop=0; loop++< colWidths[col]  + 2;){
                        line+=" ";
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (loop=0; loop++<=colWidths[col]+1;){
                    line+=" ";
                }
            }
        }
        if (!line.trim().equals("")){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        line="";

        for ( col = -1; ++col < nodes[0].length;) {
            node = nodes[row][col];
            if (node!=null){
                if (node.equals("|")) {
                    for (loop=0; loop++< colWidths[col] - node.length() + 2;){
                        line+=" ";
                    }
                    line+=node;
                }
                else {
                    for (loop=0; loop++< colWidths[col] - node.length() + 2;){
                        line+="_";
                    }
                    line+=node;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (loop=0; loop++<=colWidths[col]+1;){
                    line+=" ";
                }
            }
        }
        if (!line.trim().equals("")){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[]a){
    String[] values = a[0].split(","); 
    N t=new N(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
    for (int i=0;i++<values.length-1;)
    t.i(Integer.parseInt(values[i]));
    t.p(t);
    t.d();
}
}`